# Javascript click() doesn't work on some elements

Tags: javascript, automation, click, web

I want to write some automation to website. Simply filling in forms and simulating clicks on elements. But for some elements JavaScript function click() doesn't work. For example it is on this page: http://www1.plus.pl/bsm/ If I do click() on "Wyślij" button, nothing happens. It is my command:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tab-button')[0].click()
```

What is wrong? Why on other elements this function works?

Comment: on some browsers `[0]` might not work if it's not an array.

Comment: Gumik - please post your solution as an answer, rather than editing it into the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With yours help I found the solution:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.querySelectorAll('.tab-button')[0].dispatchEvent(evt)
```

Notice that it should be `mousedown` event rather than `click`. Some sites are done in a different way than others. Another important thing is 3rd parameter. It should be set to `false` (in this particular case). It sets `cancelable` value. Without this set to `false` it doesn't work.

Thank you for all answers!

Comment: Not working for me. I had Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470302/is-there-anything-special-in-the-following-dom-that-makes-it-non-clickable?noredirect=1#comment136577543_77470302

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tab-button')[0].dispatchEvent(event)
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tab-button')[0].fireEvent(event)
```

is the way you could do it... but trying it on the site, the 'click' event isn't bound to that element

**EDITED**
See [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Comment: It gives the following errors:

Unhandled InternalException: WRONG_ARGUMENTS_ERR; 

fireEvent' is not a function. This element has no 'click' event, so why something happens if i click on it with mouse? Is it some different way?

Comment: Some browsers support fireEvent, some dispatchEvent. 
You should do a if(...dispatchEvent) { ...dispatchEvent('click') } first (and the same for .fireEvent.

Maybe the event bound isn't click. Maybe it's mousedown?

Comment: You are right. It is mousedown event. But it is more complicated than you wrote. This code works well:
`var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getElementsByClassName('tab-button')[0].dispatchEvent(evt);`

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your valuable comment. I updated the question with solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that (at least in some) versions of IE, dispatch event doesn't exist - you need to use fireEvent - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that it is because the browser you are testing on has no native support for `.getElementsByClassName`. Try using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) instead, or assign your element an ID and use `document.getElementById`. E.g.:

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("tab-button")[0];
btn.click();
```

Comment: I'm 100% sure that I get proper element. I've tested it on 3 different web browsers: Firefox, Opera, QtWebKit.

Answer (score 0):

are you doing this after `Loaded` on the `body` tag, if some elements don't click it may be due to them not being loaded into the DOM when the script runs.

Comment: This object I search for is loaded. I can get some info from this object but click() doesn't work.

Comment: you are firing a click event and not binding an event am i right?

Comment: Anyone find something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some elements need `dispatchEvent()`, and others need a plain `click()`. To build on gumik's answer (thanks!), here's my copy-pasta for quick-and-dirty Javascript automation that just needs to click things:

```js
function click(node) {
  var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  node.dispatchEvent(evt);
  
  node.click();
}
```

Usage:

```
var button = document.querySelector(".somecssclassname");
click(button);
```